# The Night Terror and Candy

Tags: wasteland-2-directors-cut

In the Wasteland 2: Director's Cut what happens after you give The Night Terror 20 pieces of 'candy', it just sits there for me now without moving and appears to be in a sleep state.   When does it wake up?  And what happens when it does?   Also, do I need to go back where I left it to start something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation just kill him. He'll explode around 2000 damage done and you'll get a hefty 3,200 XP. The only other option is to not feed him and then he'll just follow you around and soak damage.

So you either get a pretty useful distraction for enemies or you get a nice chunk of XP.